# String escaping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

I have a string like this

```
var str = 'C:\fake\p\ath\some.jpg';
```

I tried many variants using `str.replace`, like this:

```
var str = "C:\fake\p\ath\some.jpg";
str = str.replace(/\\/g, "\\");
alert(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QBgLs/1/

But it does not work correctly, what is the right solution?

Comment: You've said a lot about what how you've tried to do whatever it is you want to achieve, not haven't actually said what that is!

Comment: So I have string `str = 'C:\fake\p\ath\some.jpg'` ---- I need obtain from this string, escaped string: `C:\\fake\\p\\ath\\some.jpg`

Comment: The problem is that your original string is not what you think it is. JavaScript is interpreting stuff like `\f` etc as escape codes. See Pointy's answer.

Comment: Quite surprising you were even allowed to ask this FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Escape+backslash+%5Bjavascript%5D

Comment: You cannot escape single backslashes *after* the string was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to double the backslashes in the string:

```
var str = 'C:\\fake\\p\\ath\\some.jpg';
```